# Can not enable contract based API in Acumatica Framework 6.X

Tags: acumatica

Unfortunately, I can not manage to enable contract based api in acumatica framework 6.1. See screen:

[image: Web Service Endpoint Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web API is only available on fully functional Acumatica ERP instances. You should install Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard and create new Acumatica ERP website to be able to use Contract-Based API.